# Kак преобразовать кракозябры (Мнемоники) обратно?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, кодировка

Парсю HTML для выявления всех js и css ресурсов. После добавления содержания всех найденных файлов записываю  обратно в HTML получившийся код  вот такой функцией:

```
 fs.writeFileSync("newindex.html", $.html());
```

Такой функцией-то все отлично работает. Потом я добавил русский текст в html файл  - он поломался при преобразовании (в новом html файле вылезли Мнемоники). Как их убрать?

Comment: На каком-то из этапов изменилась кодировка. Везде должна быть utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

По-умолчанию используется utf-8. Но можно указать и явно. Это помогает:

```
 fs.writeFileSync('index.html','$©Это хорошо!', {encoding:'utf-8'});
```